# Daily data for 15 years and still "time series has no or less than 2 periods"

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working on daily data (number of articles written on a certain subject). I used read.zoo() to create a times series object:

```
 Date_diffusion             n         
 Min.   :1995-01-01   Min.   : 1.000  
 1st Qu.:2002-05-21   1st Qu.: 1.000  
 Median :2008-09-09   Median : 2.000  
 Mean   :2008-08-06   Mean   : 3.315  
 3rd Qu.:2015-01-10   3rd Qu.: 4.000  
 Max.   :2021-03-07   Max.   :62.000
```

My aim is to perform times series decomposition to identify monthly and weekly seasonalities.
When I launch ts_decompose() I get the error:

```
Error in stats::decompose(ts.obj, type = type) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Now, there appears to be some montly and weekly seasonality (by counting articles per month and weekday), for example weekly:

[image: Data per weekday]

But I would like to get a better picture with decomposition.

Is the error due to the scarse number of observations per day? Or it's because there is no real seasonality?

Comment: it's hard to help without a portion of the relevant data, but one thing that i notice is that the y axis is called "factor" are you sure the data you send to your function is in "date" format

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes it's in date format, I just used forcats for visualisation.